# Why chromedriver is not recognized when an environment variable is created in windows 10?

Tags: chromedriver, windows-10

I created a testing project and set an environment variable. Then run the project and it could not find the chromedriver. Then I set a path inside the project to the chromedriver. It worked.

The problem occurs when I set an environment variable only.

I tried setting the path in Windows 7 and no problem occurred. Is there any special method to set an environment variable in windows 10. I tried several tutorials too.

Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: What tool are you using? You probably need to set path to chromedriver manually.

Comment: I see no code at all.  How are you setting the environment variable(s)?

Comment: I tried setting path manually. It works. Problem occurs when environment variable is set

Comment: If you are using an IntelliJ IDEA or something similar then you need to set it in the IDE. It is a sad truth of using these high-level tools.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use an API that downloads the Webdriver, sets the environment variables and removes the issue of updating the path if the project is shared on another computer/server? This would do : https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Comment: I would refrain from getting deep in another huge dependency. I always managed my drivers with PATH and a symlink to the current driver (+ alias or two to change symlinks).

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar issue with Window 10. In Window 10 with intelliJ I found that 
for `System.getProperty("user.dir")` it comes with backslash. i.e `c:\user\qa`

I resolved it by replacing backslash with forward slash like below

```
String chromePath= System.getProperty("user.dir").replaceAll("\\\\","/") + "/src/driver/chromedriver.exe
```